# Underline Spinner Created Programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, underline

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buS7i.png)  How to add underline to a spinner which is created programmatically in java:

```
spinner2 = new Spinner(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
Getspinnerdata();
inouttypec.add(spinner2);
textInputLayout2.addView(spinner2);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "underline spinner". You could describe it, add a drawing, ... And please describe what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your style as `R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Spinner_Underlined`

Mode = Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN | Spinner.MODE_DIALOG

```
new Spinner(this, null, 0, R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Spinner_Underlined, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN)
```